# Will my Power Automate Flow will remain authenticated if I don’t login for long period of time

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector

I am the owner of an important Power Automate Flow in my organisation and I am going on 12 months' leave.  My account will be active for the entire period, but I won't necessarily be logging in.  Will the Flow continue to run with me as the owner, or does Power Automate require that I am actively using my account for other stuff to stay authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

It will continue to run as long as it is triggered. However, flows that do not run for a period of time (from memory I think it’s 90 days) will be turned off.

The suggestion here is to use some kind of service account for this operation (if possible) in future.

I created a flow almost two years ago at a company that runs under a service account (technically it’s just a generic user as it has email access, etc.) and it continues to until this day. No one logs in as that user and I know that for a fact.